# What is Person person in class Order?

Tags: java

I was viewing a Java project and I found these classes :

```
public abstract class Person { 

int id;
String name;
String phone;
String gender;

private static int idIncrementer = 0;

public Person(String name, String phone, String gender)
{
    idIncrementer++;
    this.id = idIncrementer;
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.gender = gender;
}


public class Order {
 int id;
String date;
boolean isPaid;
Person person;
ArrayList<Product> products;}
```

What is `Person person` in class `Order`? Is it a `Person` object and if it is, why is it written like that?

Comment: What do you mean why is it written like that? There's no other (valid) way to declare a Person instance field

Comment: Because whoever wrote that code decided that an order is related to a `Person` and it contains a product and a date, etc. Honestly: what do you not understand about this?

Comment: He/she may not be well acquainted with OOP concepts.

Comment: _why is it written like that?_ - _Sometimes things happen that are just out of your control_ (cit).

Comment: It is a variable that can hold a reference to a Person instance. It's written like that because that's the way to write it.

Comment: Google "java beginners tutorial" and follow a couple of them, they should explain what objects are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Person* is an *abstract class* defined by the programmer. Now, *Person person* is a **reference variable to the object of the subclass of the *Person* class**, as we cannot create an object of the *Person* class (since it is an abstract class). For more concepts on Object Oriented Programming (OOP), visit https://www.javatpoint.com/java-oops-concepts